# Flipboard iPad app integration

Tags: feature-request, ipad

It would be great to be able to view stackoverflow content with the Flipboard app. Totally new level of convenience. In order to accomplish this I think it is sufficient to provide more rich RSS feeds, and also a feed for stackexchange inbox.

Current integration: [image: pic]

Answer (score 10):

I can't see how Flipboard, which describes itself using the tagline

> Your social magazine.

would be a good place to host or view Stack Overflow content.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipboard) describes Flipboard as

> a social-network aggregation, magazine-format application software for Apple touch-screen devices, including the iPad, iPhone and iPod Touch.

Considering Stack Overflow is *not* a social media or social networking site, we don't seem to fit very well within their model.

And even if it *was* a good fit, I don't think this should become an official feature. There is a [public API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage), so you could always write your own templates/application.

What's wrong with the mobile theme you already get when you visit the page?

Comment: Cody I was trying to attach a photo but I lack 10 reputation. I think that typical web approach "long list scrolled vertically" contains an embedded psychological tension in it. I find it unnatural. The "flip page" approach is IMO different. I feel relaxed when flipping pages. I would argue that a page is a consistent object, that has finite "dimensions" and this is more compatible with how humans receive information.

Comment: @Steffen: You can still use the free hosting service http://imgur.com/ to upload your image, then just edit a link into your answer. You won't be able to make the image appear inline, but someone can edit it for you.

Comment: Flipboard's tagline implies it uses *your* social contacts to build a magazine, not that flipboard itself is a social network. Also, it's a pretty good RSS reader.

Comment: I have to agree with @Sathya here, it's not an all a social magazine like you describe, that's just where it gets a list of things to show from...it's not at all social itself.  I use it as an RSS reader as well, it's quite good and would fit fine with SO content included.